# How do I prevent this Error Message

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have created a VBA access application to find a PDF file in a folder by doing one sweep to get all the sub-folders in the root folder. Then another sweep to collect and compare all the file names to the one that is selected. We are then using the following code to open the file when it is found:

```
Private Sub Command132_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command132_Click

Dim rootFolder  As String
Dim subFolder   As String
Dim fileSpec    As String
Dim filename    As String
Dim foundfile   As String
Dim filepath    As String
Dim subfolders() As String
Dim co As String
Dim intSubFolderCount As Integer

rootFolder = "T:\Scanned Work Orders (Archives)\"
subFolder = Dir(rootFolder & "*.*", vbDirectory)

'*** Get subfolders in array ***
While subFolder <> ""
    If subFolder <> "." And subFolder <> ".." Then
        ReDim Preserve subfolders(intSubFolderCount)
        subfolders(intSubFolderCount) = subFolder
        intSubFolderCount = intSubFolderCount + 1

        Debug.Print subFolder
    End If
    subFolder = Dir()
Wend

'*** Loop over array and find files ***
    For intSubFolderCount = 0 To UBound(subfolders)
    fileSpec = Trim(Me.Combo_History) & "*.pdf"
    co = subfolders(intSubFolderCount)
    filename = Dir(rootFolder & subfolders(intSubFolderCount) & "\" & fileSpec)
   Do While filename <> ""
        filepath = rootFolder & subfolders(intSubFolderCount)
        foundfile = filepath & "\" & filename
        Application.FollowHyperlink foundfile
        GoTo Exit_Command132_Click
        Exit Do
    Loop

Next intSubFolderCount

MsgBox "No Scanned work order found for " & Me.Combo_History & "!"


Exit_Command132_Click:
   Exit Sub

Err_Command132_Click:

Select Case Err.Number
    Case 52
        MsgBox "No Scanned work order found for " & Me.Combo_History & "!"
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description
  End Select
End Sub
```

But on some of the computers in my office they get this error message:

"Some Files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer.
It is important to be certain that this file is from a trustworthy source.

Would you like to open this file?"

Is it possible to suppress this? We are running windows 7 professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a windows feature. Microsoft have KB on removing it here.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925757

It is possible to use VBA to change the registry settings, but follow the KB instructions first to ensure it solves your issue.